# Selenium chrome driver socks proxy configuration

Tags: selenium, configuration, proxy, socks, selenium-chromedriver

I am having troubles in setting socks proxy for chrome driver

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setSocksProxy(ProxyHelper.PROXY_HOST + ":" + ProxyHelper.PROXY_PORT);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

This configuration gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: proxy from unknown error: proxyType is 'manual' but no manual proxy capabilities were found
```

I think it expects me to fill http, ftp and ssl proxies. But if I fill them; error doesnt raise but my proxy does not work properly too as it tries to use it like http proxy rather than socks proxy.

What can I do?

Comment: How did you fix this error?

Comment: @JobaDiniz See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28891213/363573

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + host + ":" + port);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using this chromium arg?

```
--proxy-server="socks5://host:port"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as ff_options
random_proxy = "142.54.61.98:120"
options = ff_options()
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": random_proxy,
    "ftpProxy": random_proxy,
    "sslProxy": random_proxy
}
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("media.peerconnection.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("media.navigator.enabled", False)
# profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_profile=profile,
                           firefox_options=options)
```